# Formatting numbers in a table view

Tags: c#, format, number-formatting, format-string

I am formatting the numbers displayed in my table view. The numbers are formatted correctly - i.e. 21000 displays as 21,000.

However, if the number in the table is 0, the number displayed is 00.

```
Column.FormatString = "{0:0,0}";
```

Above is the code I am using for this.

Comment: What `table view`? What controll are you using? Is this a desktop, web application, some kind of report control?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in some cultures a comma is a decimal separator

Comment: @trailmax this isn't a culture-specific string. That's the thousand separator, replaced by the culture-specific separator

Comment: It's a RadGridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the docs on [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), `0` means that a non-significant `0` should always be displayed, even if there is no corresponding digit. For example:

- `String.Format("{0:0.0}",0.6)` will display `0.6` while
- `String.Format("{0:#.0}",0.6)` will display `.6`

The same holds for the thousand separator although the result is rather... unexpected. Since there's no thousand separator, a `0` is displayd but `,` is not :

- `String.Format("{0:0,0}",0)` will display `00` while
- `String.Format("{0:#,0}",0)` will display `0`

`String.Format` allows separate formats for positive, negative and *zeros*. If you want to retain the leading `0` but display only a single `0` for zero, you can use

```
String.Format("{0:0,0;-0,0;0}",0);
```

Comment: Great answer! Thankyou, been struggling with that for a while. Was ready to just accept the double 0 haha.